# How to implement a ifdef in macro for declare variable?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

SOLVED,
I found a solution to declare variable through macro and macro syntax,

> the declare.c is generate by other tools, so I can't modify it.

[I_VAR.c]

```
#define _DECLARE_VAR_I TYPE NAME;
#define _DECLARE_VAR_U
#define DECLARE_VAR(TYPE, NAME, CLASS) \
_DECLARE_VAR_##CLASS(TYPE, NAME)
#include "declare.h"
#undef _DECLARE_VAR_I
#undef _DECLARE_VAR_U
```

[U_VAR.c]

```
#define _DECLARE_VAR_I
#define _DECLARE_VAR_U TYPE NAME;
#define DECLARE_VAR(TYPE, NAME, CLASS) \
_DECLARE_VAR_##CLASS(TYPE, NAME)
#include "declare.h"
#undef _DECLARE_VAR_I
#undef _DECLARE_VAR_U
```

---

I have a macro to declare global variable, and the macro has a syntax call "class" for separate those declaration to different C file, but the preprocessor show me an error, because I use "ifdef" in macro.

does any idea? thanks!

(1)macro

```
#define DECLARE_VAR(TYPE, NAME, CLASS) \
#ifdef CLASS \
TYPE NAME; \
#endif
```

(2)
[declare.h] generate by tools

```
DECLARE_VAR(int, i0, I)
DECLARE_VAR(int, i1, I)
DECLARE_VAR(int, i2, I)
DECLARE_VAR(int, u0, U)
DECLARE_VAR(int, u1, U)
DECLARE_VAR(int, u2, U)
```

(3)
[I_Var.c]

```
#define I
#include "declare.h"
```

[U_Var.c]

```
#define U
#include "declare.h"
```

it's possble to separate variable to different file through macro parameter?

Comment: I don't see the point of your macro. What is your goal?

Comment: for declare specified variable in different file through macro parameter CLASS

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you want to achieve. There might be a simple and straightforward answer to your _actual_ problem. I have the feeling that the inclusion of `declare.h` and the macros obscure your real intension.

Answer (score 1):

You want to conditionally define stuff. Don't make the parameter that has to be defined an argument of the macro. Just use straightforward `#ifdef`s, which makes it immediately clear¹ which block is defined.

```
#ifdef I
    int i0;
    int i1;
    int i2;
#end

#ifdef U
    unsigned int u0;
    unsigned int u1;
    unsigned int u2;
#endif
```

Of course, now you have to find a way to make the rest of the code distiguish between `i0` and `u0`. Perhaps you want to define variables of the same type, but not of the same names. Pehaps you don't want `#ifdef` here, but a defined type:

```
#define M_TYPE
#include "declare.h"
```

and in `declare.h`:

```
#ifndef M_TYPE
#error "Forgot to define M_TYPE"
#end

M_TYPE i0;
M_TYPE i1;
M_TYPE i2;
```

Here, you cannot include `declare.h` twice from the same `*.c` file with different types.

________
¹ in this short example, anyway.

Comment: I need, if define the class like "#define U" in the file top, then the include "declare.h" "U" part is effect and "I" part is not effect. thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the code above do that, only with `CLASS` instead of `U`?

Comment: in above case, the macro parameter CLASS mean "I" or "U". but the macro ifdef is illegal

Comment: Okay, now I see. I've rewritten my answer. (I guess your example is just made up, otherwise I'm not sure why you want to declare three variables of the same type with another name.)

Comment: the post is updated, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a macro(), just do:

```
#ifdef I
    int i0;
    ...
#end

#ifdef U
    int u2;
    ...
#endif
```

Be aware that use of macro's and conditional compilation obscures things; so only use this when really necessary.

I have my doubts about putting both sets of definitions in the same `declare.h`. Please consider having a `declareU.h` and a `declareI.h` and simple `#include` either one in your `.c` files.

Then, your `declare.h` is misnamed because you're not declaring variables but instead are defining them. It's bad practice to define variables in a header file because you'll end up with multiple instances of them in your program if you include the header in multiple source files.

Comment: the post is updated, thanks for the answer